# How to assign a nullable int property in an anonymous type in LINQ with a Union?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two select statements in LINQ with a `Union`.

A `RoleID` needs to have a null value in one of the selects. I am getting the error below.

If the `RoleID` has a value, it works fine. Reports is an EF entity with properties.

It can be anything in this example. Example is simple for illustration purposes.

**Code in LinqPad:**

```
var list = Reports.Select(r => new
    {
        RoleID = 3
    })
    .Union(Reports.Select(r => new
    {
        RoleID = new Nullable<int>()    <= error
        //RoleID = (int?) null          <= error
        //RoleID = 4                    <= works
    }));
list.Dump();
```

How do I make it work with a null value and make RoleID of type int?

**Error Message:**

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union(System.Linq.ParallelQuery, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments
>   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your first `Select` query returns sequence of anonymous objects where `RoleID` have type `int`. To union both sequences they should have same type of anonymous objects. So you need to change first query:

```
var list = Reports.Select(r => new
                {
                    RoleID = (int?)3
                })
```

Keep in mind, in second query you also should have nullable `RoleID` to match type of anonymous object:

```
 .Union(Reports.Select(r => new
    {
        RoleID = new Nullable<int>() 
        //RoleID = (int?)null
        //RoleID = (int?)4
    }));
```

BTW Why have union on two selects from same source? Looks like you over simplified your sample queries.

Answer (score 8):

You need `RoleID` to be nullable in the first anonymous class as well:

```
Reports.Select(r => new
               {
                   RoleID = (int?)3
               }
```

See also these questions:

- Two anonymous classes will have be share the same type if they use the same properties, with the same types, at the same order: [is order of field important in anonymous types automatic initialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2154414/7586)
- You can also create a list of an anonymous type and add to it: [Add an anonymous class of object to an anonymous list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564119/add-an-anonymous-class-of-object-to-an-anonymous-list)
- Also, you usually want to use `Concat`, not `Union`: [Union Vs Concat in Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417556/union-vs-concat-in-linq)

Comment: Any comment on the downvote? The OP has indicated that `RoleID = 4` works for them...

Comment: Not my downvote, but didn't you change answer? Seems like you originally had changes to `Union` part of query

Comment: I need RoleID to have a value in one of the selects. Just like in SQL where you can assign a null to a select value and in another union select you can select an actual column in the same position. Concat doesn't make a difference. It gives the same error.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy - Not that I can recall. *Meybe* I starter with `r => new` but edited it in 5 seconds.

Comment: @Tony_Henrich - `RoleID` will have a value in the first object, but you will have to use `.RoleID.Value`. You cannot have a list of object of the **same type**, but when a property is sometimes nullable. You can't do that with notmal classes either. As for Union and Concat - You generally want to use `Concat` - this is like `union` vs. `union all` in SQL.